# How do we validate uniqueness on an Azure Table Storage column?

Tags: azure-table-storage, unique-constraint

The only primary key / uniqueness validation enforced by Azure Table Storage is partition key + row key. If I want any other column to be unique, I need to check this condition at the application layer.

```
if(service.GetEmailAddress(emailAddress) == null) {
   // email address is not yet registered by a user
   // persist user data to the database
}
else
{
   // display an error message
}
```

What I'm curious about is what happens if there are an X number of concurrent users that are trying to save the same column value to the same table. What's the safe way to make sure no duplicate values are entered below a specific column that does not have a UNIQUE constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see Azure Table Storage is not designed for such purpose. As they say the goal of Azure Table Storage is to :

> Storing Data for Efficient Retrieval and Persistence

So given that I think this may be not the solution you are looking for, I think you should evaluate the possibility of moving your data Azure SQL. Because in Azure Table Storage (Or any other NoSQL implementation) the concept of COLUMN doesn't have a much value, since you are allowed to save entities of different types in the same table.

Further reading [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796231.aspx), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322525/sql-vs-nosql-for-an-inventory-management-system).

Comment: Hi Geethanga, I'm in the market for a scalable database solution on Azure. Using SQL Azure by itself is not a good idea since you're limited to 150GB at the time, and at one point I need to think about horizontal partitioning. I've been playing with SQL Azure Federation lately, but I can't create unique constraints in that either. Each unique index must include the federated column.

Comment: In your context it's true. The size of your database really puts  you in the trouble. But as I said earlier I think it's not good to look at Table Storage in the columns perspective. Because you have different types of entities in the same table. That leaves you with only one solution that is to handle this in the business layer. I think that is where you should head for.